# How recursive method works in c#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, debugging, recursion, console-application

I'm having hard time understanding recursive method calling.

This is the code sample below that i tried to figure it out? Please explain how it works.

How 'num'(parameter) value is getting decremented and incremented?

```
class green
 {

    public int fact(int num)
    {
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
        if (num == 1)
        {
            return 1;

        }
        else
        {
            a = num;
            Console.Write(a);
            Console.Write(" #a ");
            b=fact(num - 1); // How many time's this line will be executed?
            Console.Write(b);
            Console.Write(" #b " );
            c=a*b;
```

> //How the final value of b is 6 , a is 4?

```
            Console.Write(c);
            Console.Write(" #c ");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        return c;

    }



    public void display()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("fact : {0}", fact(4));
    }

}


class _Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        green g=new green(); 

        g.display();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint where you're interested in and keep hammering F10 / F11.

Comment: This is not a school.. You don't have any programming problem except the fact you're too lazy to do a research on the topic. Recursion is well documented on NUMEROUS websites and it's one of the easiest things on programming...

Comment: _How 'num'(parameter) value is getting decremented_ - when you call `fact(num - 1)`. But do note that that recursive call means there is another `num` on the stack. It doesn't replace the previous one.

Comment: @walther I agree about SO not being a school, and about there being many resources on the web to learn about recursion, but calling someone lazy is a little harsh, no?

Comment: Thanks henk i does'nt know how to place my question here, that why i asked in general, so that i can get the answer to it. That's what i'm wondering about how the value of num is not getting decremented.

Comment: Your `b = fact(num - 1)` will not decrement num. Perhaps you need to make it: `b = fact(--num)`?  `--num` is the same as `num = num - 1`, only it happens **before** calling `fact()`.

Comment: @ walther, i know this is not a school, i tried searching for it, but i dint get the answer what happens internally. that's y i turned to SO.

Comment: Internally? Recursion is just a function that calls itself over and over, while it makes sense. There's no magic behind it, nor any technical complicated stuff.

Comment: This is recursion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19426875/how-recursive-method-works-in-c

Comment: @codecaster i tied putting breakpoint, but what happens is that, the num value which has decremented is getting incremented by 1 till it reach 4. So i don't understand way it is calling the method, as i'm new to programming.

Comment: Just put a breakpoint in your main method and when hit, keep pressing F11 (Step Into). Add a Watch to num as soon as you encounter it and keep stepping into, closely watching the Watch window. We can explain it step by step, but you'll learn more if you see it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your class to this...

```
class Green
{
    public int fact(int num)
    {
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
        if (num == 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            a = num;
            Console.Write(a);
            Console.Write(" #a ");
            return a * fact(num - 1); 
        }
    }
}
```

...then you will get a result of 24 when the input is 4.    Others have commented on the algorithmic flaw in your original question.

Apologies for the broken format, it seems the SO formatter is on the blink...

Comment: I'm getting the answer correct. But what i expected is just to get the basic working on recursion method, so that i'll get aware of what needs to be touched or how it can be used, as i said i new to programming c# im having hard time here.

Comment: @Vignesh, the line c=a*b; was not being executed until *AFTER* the recursion had been executed.  That's why you thought it was returning a 6 (from 3*2).  But the 6 was only an interim result from the first pass.  A well-defined recursive function should have no code after the recursive call is made.

Comment: does b takes the interim result as 6? so it multiplies with a=4 gives 24? When it will stop returning the c value or when it will know that it reached the answer?

Comment: Dude, all well-formed recursive functions regress towards the BASE CASE.  It is the end-point sentinel that marks the last rule.  You need to understand the code you wrote from a theory viewpoint before attempting the technical implementation.